# issues with delete item in array with swift 3

Tags: swift3

i have an problem with delete item from array i try to solve it long time but i couldn't

my problem is :
i have  dictionary[Int:String] which contain items, the user select these items from the table view cell for delete it after,
this  dictionary have an item from type string and with key key is indexPath.row 
the following my dictionary code:

```
var dictionaryOfItems = [Int:String]()
dictionaryOfItems.updateValue("Banana", forKey: 0)
dictionaryOfItems.updateValue("Cucumber", forKey: 3)
```

and i have an array which contains array of item type string
the following code is my array :

```
var array :[String] = ["Banana","Apple","Orange","Cucumber","lettuce","Milk","Tea"]
```

i need to delete items from array which dictionarOfItems contain it's

when i try to delete the items from array i get the error message index out off range how can i fix it please

the following is my full code:

```
var array :[String] = ["Banana","Apple","Orange","Cucumber","lettuce","Milk","Tea"]

var dictionaryOfItems = [Int:String]()
dictionaryOfItems.updateValue("Banana", forKey: 0)
dictionaryOfItems.updateValue("Cucumber", forKey: 3)


for (index,_) in dictionaryOfItems {
    if array[index] == dictionaryOfItems[index] {
      array.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any error message. It correctly deletes `"Banana"` from the array. Also note that every time you delete something the indices shift, so after deleting `"Banana"`, `"Cucumber"` will be at index `2` and will therefore not be deleted on the next iteration.

Comment: Yes i know the array is shift it this only delete banana from array and what is about the second item it is not delet it how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of explicitly removing item from your array, you can simply `filter` using a predicate:

- Filtering our elements whose associated array index (say `idx`) corresponds to a key in you dictionary `dictionaryOfItems` whose value equals that of the array element.

E.g.:

```
array = array.enumerated()
    .filter { (idx, _) in dictionaryOfItems[idx] != array[idx] }
    .map { $0.1 }
print(array) // ["Apple", "Orange", "lettuce", "Milk", "Tea"]
```

It seems like quite a roundabout way, however; to use a dictionary to track the every-changing element *indices* in your mutatable array (this, in particular, is the reason of your runtime error). Are you sure you want a dictionary to track indices and elements in an array, where the latter is, inherently, a collection of elements and associated indices?

On another note, if your predicate is in fact simpler (just removes items which are present as *values* in a dictionary; without need of matching tracked indices), you could use a much simpler `filter` approach:

```
array = array.filter { !dictionaryOfItems.values.contains($0) }
print(array) // ["Apple", "Orange", "lettuce", "Milk", "Tea"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array :[String] = ["Banana","Apple","Orange","Cucumber","lettuce","Milk","Tea"]

var dictionaryOfItems = [Int:String]()
dictionaryOfItems.updateValue("Banana", forKey: 0)
dictionaryOfItems.updateValue("Cucumber", forKey: 3)

var indexes = dictionaryOfItems.keys.sorted().reversed()

for index in indexes {
    if array[index] == dictionaryOfItems[index] {
        array.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```